# Django request.user gives Anonymous in the response view after callback from payment gateway

Tags: django

Payment gateway (3rd party website) sends post data to a callback url (my website) which can be accessed using request.POST

But request.user gives Anonymous in the response view. On adding decorator @login_required to the view, request.POST becomes empty but request.user returns authenticathed user.

I need to access both request.user and request.POST form data at the same time to save transaction into database.

```
# @login_required
def response(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        MERCHANT_KEY = settings.MERCHANT_KEY
        data_dict = {}
        for key in request.POST:
                if request.POST[key]:
                    data_dict[key] = int(request.POST[key])
        PaymentHistory.objects.create(user=request.user, **data_dict)
        return render(request, "response.html", {"paytm": data_dict})
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payment gateway response should never be logged in because that request will always spawn a new session that is not related to the user interacting with your website.  The better way to handle it is to have each user post back to a separate url:

e.g.,

https://example.com/payment/callback/random_token

And have that random_token be associated with a username in the database.

Comment: Thanks, I used your approach but instead of generating unique user_id and storing it in database, I found another approach. Form data contained Customer_ID where I passed user's unique attribute (email) with which I was able to get user refeerence - User.objects.get(email=Customer_ID) and problem was solved!